# How to pass data to shader constant buffer register bN (N > 15)

Tags: graphics, shader, directx, game-engine, hlsl

[Environment]
DirectX11 (FeatureLevel 11.0)
HLSL Shader Version vs_5_0/ps_5_0

I defined common constant buffers in my code (named Common.hlsli)

```
float4x4    g_VS_Test0 : register( b0 );
float4x4    g_VS_Test1 : register( b1 );
float4      g_VS_Test2 : register( b2 );
float4      g_VS_Test3 : register( b3 );
float4x4    g_PS_Test4 : register( b4 );
float4      g_PS_Test5 : register( b5 );
float4      g_PS_Test6 : register( b6 );
float4      g_PS_Test7 : register( b7 );
float4      g_PS_Test8 : register( b8 );
float4      g_PS_Test9 : register( b9 );
float4      g_PS_Test10 : register( b10 );
float4      g_PS_Test11 : register( b11 );
float4      g_PS_Test12 : register( b12 );
float4      g_PS_Test13 : register( b13 );
float4      g_PS_Test14 : register( b14 );
float4      g_PS_Test15 : register( b15 );
float4      g_PS_Test16 : register( b16 );
float4      g_PS_Test17 : register( b17 );
float4      g_PS_Test18 : register( b18 );
float4      g_PS_Test19 : register( b19 );
float4      g_PS_Test20 : register( b20 );
```

For example, FileA.hlsl including above file uses b0, b4, b18 and b19.

I thoght I should set 0, 4, 18, 19 V(P)SSetConstantBuffers first param 'UINT StartSlot'.

But over 14(or15) is set, the error occured blow.

```
D3D11 CORRUPTION: ID3D11DeviceContext::PSSetConstantBuffers: First parameter is out of range.
```

According to Microsoft official doc, we only use 15 constant buffers.

I defined over 15 constant buffers in shader code but actual used only 4.

Are there any ways to solve this?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't store more than a single vector/matrix in a given constant buffer? If there is a reason, then you're out of luck, as you can't have more than 16 constant buffers, you'll need to find some variables that can be put into a constant buffer together.

Comment: In past code, c0 ... cN is used in DX9.  (to single Vector)
So, I wrote same style.

But pack 4 vectors to cbuffer, this problem has been solved!
Thank you for teaching.